# How to configure npm build to produce the same hashes for the same content?

Tags: javascript, npm, build

If I run `npm run build` twice, I get 2 different build/static/js/main.xxx.js (where xxx seems random)

Given that I have not modified the files, how (if I can) do I configure npm to generate the same hashes if I do not modify the files ?

Comment: Got some more info? It's not even clear if you're using webpack or not. If so, what does the configuration look like?

Comment: @Caramiriel Trying to get a clean and consistent repro, I've deleted node_modules and package-lock.json then npm install && npm run build && npm run build -> now, the files always have the same hashes ...
I do not understand how this is linked + I do not manage to get get back to previous state (even with old package-lock.json)
I think that I tangled with the file system in some way, but no clue
Thanks for taking your time and sorry for this false question ...